# Permisos directorios en Laravel

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, permisos

Tengo un *Laravel 7* en local, con *Ubuntu 18.04* + *Apache2*.

Los permisos de los directorios cambian sólos de cuando en cuando, por ejemplo, de los subdirectorios de "storage", impidiendo que Laravel compile vistas o escriba logs...

Normalmente ejecuto:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R storage/*
```

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de escribir nuevos `log`.

Principalmente se debe a los permisos que tiene asignado el usuario que intenta crear el `log`. Los usuarios básicos son `www-data` y `root`.

> Los permisos de los directorios cambian sólos

No es que se cambien solos. Cada día se debe crear un **nuevo** archivo con nuevos permisos y los permisos que diste al archivo del día anterior quedan de lado.

En la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/logging#building-log-stacks) podrás ver que, por defecto, laravel utiliza `0644` para la creación de `logs`.

Puedes cambiar eso utilizando la opción de configuración `permission`:

`config/logging.php`:

```
'daily' => [
   'driver' => 'daily',
   'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
   'level' => 'debug',
   'days' => 14,
   'permission' => 0666,
],
```

Puedes utilizar `0666`, o `0775` dependiendo de tus necesidades.

Comment: Bien como comentar, puede ser también que el proyecto pertenezca a un grupo y los archivos al crearse sean de otro, lo puedes confirmar al hacer `ls -l` en el proyecto, si es el caso lo puedes cambiar de grupo con el comando `chown -R grupo:grupo /carpeta_a_cambiar`

Comment: @tecnobyte me inclino más a que sea esto lo que pasa, tengo que darle permisos a la carpeta donde compila las vistas varias veces al día...

Comment: @tecnobyte no funciono. *storage* tenía como grupo root:root, lo cambie a php:php. Tiene los permisos: drwxrwxrwx

Comment: Lo debes cambiar a www-data, ese es el grupo